# Django API Client Get Request with Payload

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am looking to see if this is possible. If I send a get request with body in postman I get back results matching what I need.

Can we send a get request with a body using the APIClient?

Here is my code;

```
def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        HistoryLog.objects.create(username='User1', log_time='2020-05-05', logon_time='08:00', logout_time='09:00')
        HistoryLog.objects.create(username='User2', log_time='2020-05-05', logon_time='08:30', logout_time='10:00')
        HistoryLog.objects.create(username='User3', log_time='2020-05-08', logon_time='08:40', logout_time='11:00')
        HistoryLog.objects.create(username='User4', log_time='2020-05-10', logon_time='08:50', logout_time='12:00')


def test_get_data(self):

        payload = {'date': '2020-05-05', 'start_time': '06:00', 'end_time': '12:00'}

        res = self.client.get(HISTORY_URL, payload)

        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK) -- this passes.
        self.assertEqual(len(res.data), 2) -- this always come back that res.data is zero
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky, but seems to work:

```
def test_get_data(self):
    payload = {'date': '2020-05-05', 'start_time': '06:00', 'end_time': '12:00'}
    data, content_type = self.client._encode_data(payload, 'json')
    res = self.client.generic('get', HISTORY_URL, data, content_type)
    ...
```